# iOS SpriteKit run progress bar in infinite loop

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, progress-bar, skspritenode, skcropnode

TL;DR - In spritekit, In a while loop,  I'm using a for loop to do arbitrary work to delay the next call of the while loop so that my power bar doesn't run ridiculously fast. Is there a better way to make a small delay in spritekit?

Hey everyone,

I'm making a game that involves a user setting the power for a cannon before launching a projectile from it. I want the power bar to go from 0-100 then 100-0 and loop like this. The power bar runs while the user is tapping a button, and as soon as they release I calculate the speed of the projectile based on where the power bar is. My plan was to use a SKCropNode to show a progress bar image based on the progress of the bar. This works well using the following class for the progress bar:

```
//Progress bar Header

#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface CustomProgressBar : SKCropNode
- (void) setProgress:(CGFloat) progress;
@end

//Progress bar Implemenation

#import "CustomProgressBar.h"
@implementation CustomProgressBar

- (id)init {
if (self = [super init]) {
    self.maskNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor whiteColor]    size:CGSizeMake(50,20)];
    SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"progressBar.jpg"];
    sprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    [self addChild:sprite];
}
return self;
}

- (void) setProgress:(CGFloat) progress {
self.maskNode.xScale = progress;
}

@end
```

and I use this function to update the power bar (which uses a for loop to delay the update of the bar):

```
-(void)runPowerBar {
    i = 1;
    progressBar.hidden = NO;
    power = 10;
    while (!self.isStarted){
        float prog = power * 0.00001;
        multiplier = prog;
        [progressBar setProgress:prog];

        for(int z = 0; z < 100; z++){
           // this is bad and inconsistent, need a new way
           // to delay the next call of [progressBar setProgress:prog]
        }

        power = power + i;

        if (power > 1000000) {
            i = -1;
        }
        else if (power < 1) {
            i = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I call the power bar as follows, after initializing the powerbar:

```
backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.joshnussbaum.powerBarQ", 0);
            dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
                [self runPowerBar];
            });
```

Comment: Instead of using a while loop you could rewrite your while loop logic to a method, and call this method using `dispatch_after` on a set delay. This would replace the delay the for loop creates.

Comment: I tried replacing the for for loop with the following:

       dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self setProgress:prog];
        });

and it appears to only render the update once and then it does nothing.
I also tried using a function to set the progress and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you appear to have found a solution in Sanders answer, I would advise using SKScene's [update:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Actions/Actions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH4-SW7) method, which is part of the SpriteKit rendering loop. Adding your own asynchronous calls will eventually bite you in the behind.

The `update:` method is called once every frame and should be more than enough for your needs. In this way, you also ensure not updating your power bar more than is necessary, i.e., more than once per frame.

Below image is taken from Apple's SpriteKit Programming Guide - read more on the Sprite Kit rendering loop [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKScene/update:).

[image: The steps used by an SKScene to execute the rendering loop. (Apple)]

Comment: Thanks. So now what I'm doing is I'm setting a BOOL powerGoing to YES when I start the power bar. In the update function, if powerGoing is set, then I update the progress bar. Once I launch the hero, I set powerGoing to NO. I was definitely noticing inconsistencies with the power bar speed before doing this, thanks again. I would +1 you but I don't have enough reputation >.>

Comment: Sounds good, that's how I would do it. If an answer solves your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. You don't need any reputation for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
-(void)runPowerBar 
{
    i = 1;
    progressBar.hidden = NO;
    power = 10;
    [self updatePowerBar];
}

-(void)updatePowerBar
{
    if(!self.isStarted)
    {
        float prog = power * 0.00001;
        multiplier = prog;
        [progressBar setProgress:prog];

        power = power + i;

        if (power > 1000000) 
        {
            i = -1;
        }
        else if (power < 1) 
        {
            i = 1;
        }
        dispatch_after(YOUR_DISPATCH_TIME, dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
        ^{
            [self updatePowerBar];
        });
    }
}
```